# DataTable.Select(query) take a lot of time

Tags: c#, performance, datatable, compact-framework, dataview

Here is my code:

```
public string[] RegresaprecionombreyId(DataTable tablalm, DataTable tablaep, string producto, string cliente, DateTime fecha)
{
    producto = ((int)Convert.ToDecimal(producto)).ToString();
    string precio = "0.00", preciobase = "0.00", nombre = "producto no encontrado", id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";

    if (tablaep.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string consulta = "ope_pro=" + producto + " and cliente=" + cliente + " and '" + fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' >= inicio and '" + fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' <= fin";
        DataRow[] filas = tablaep.Select(consulta);

        if (filas.Length > 0)
        {
            id = filas[0]["id"].ToString();
            nombre = filas[0]["nombre"].ToString();
            precio = filas[0]["precio"].ToString();
            preciobase = filas[0]["preciobase"].ToString();
            return new string[] { precio, nombre, id, preciobase };
        }
    }

    if (tablalm.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string consulta = "ope_pro='" + producto + "'";
        DataRow[] filas = tablalm.Select(consulta);

        if (filas.Length > 0)
        {
            id = filas[0]["id"].ToString();
            nombre = filas[0]["nombre"].ToString();
            DateTime fechatabla = Convert.ToDateTime(filas[0]["fechanue"].ToString());

            if (fecha >= fechatabla)
                precio = filas[0]["precionue"].ToString();
            else
                precio = filas[0]["precio"].ToString();

            return new string[] { precio, nombre, id, precio };
        }
    }

    return new string[] { precio, nombre, id, preciobase };
}
```

I use some times DataTable.Select(query)

Other code which uses this method is a loop and use DataTable.Select for get the account's id, after enter to this method and use DataTable.Select(query) again at 2 table
first table is a table which every account has a diferent price for every product
for example

```
account  product  price
1          1      10
1          2      11
1          3      12
2          1      11
2          2      12
2          3      13
```

If this doesn't appears at this DataTable now i look for in other table with this format

```
product  price
  1       10.5
  2       11.5
  3       11.5
```

The first datatable has 17569 rows; the second datatable has 597 rows.

Well then when I call this method

```
RegresaprecionombreyId(DataTable tablalm, DataTable tablaep, string producto, string cliente, DateTime fecha)
```

This takes about 3 or 4 second, every time I call it, and I have a loop about 3245 records, so 3245 (records) * 3 (seconds) this is more than 2 hours. How can I improve this time?

Comment: Like any other performance problem, I suggest you determine what parts are slow, and then make them faster. In this particular case, I suggest removing columns from `consulta` one at a time to see whether one column or another makes the query slow.

Comment: It looks like your query is open to SQL injection. Have you considered using parameters instead of concatenating strings?